# Does the following question regarding functions and relations make sense?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a function $f: P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \to P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ defined: $f(R)=R \cup R^{-1}$

The question I'm struggling with is "Find $f(P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}))$". My main problem is that I can't make sense out of this question. Function $f$ takes a subset of $P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$, which is a relation, and returns a sum of this relation and the opposite relation. Makes sense. But $P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ is not a relation, it's an infinite set of relations, isn't it? Perhaps they meant $\bigcup P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm just completely lost and confused...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Is it shocking as well is I define $f$ to be the function $x \mapsto x^2$ on the real numbers and I ask to show $f(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R_+$ ? If not, the same abuse is made here in a more abstract context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f:X\to Y$ induces a function $F:\wp(X)$ to $\wp(Y)$ by $F(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$ for $A\subseteq X$. Instead of explicitly introducing $F$, we often just write $f[A]$ for $\{f(x):x\in A\}$. Many — perhaps most — people further confuse the issue by writing $f(A)$ instead of $f[A]$, so that it looks as if $A$ is an element of the domain of $f$ instead of a subset of it.

Assuming that there is no typo in your source, I suspect that that is what’s intended here, and that you’re supposed to find what I would write

$$\begin{align*}
f[\wp(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)]&=\{f(R):R\in\wp(\Bbb N\times N)\}\\
&=\{f(R):R\subseteq\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\}\\
&=\{R\cup R^{-1}:R\subseteq\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Alright, thanks, it makes sense now. I knew something smelled fishy here!

Comment: @Dunno: You’re welcome.